# Receiving Packet using Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

I am new in the Socket Programming and I just want to ask something.

I was trying to create Simple Receiver and Sender packet between the Client and Server (well I am using same computer), but I having a problem...

The sending function is working properly, but I don't know how to receive the packet that was sent with exactly same size of packet.

For example, I send 5 bytes to the server from the client, I just want to server to receive only 5 bytes too, no more and no less and I want to do this with Socket, also i already include the size of packet with short (int16 2 bytes) format. Here my send packet code:

```
    public static void Send(Socket socket, byte[] buffer, int timeout)
    {
        int startTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
        int sent = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        int size = buffer.Length;

        // Add size of packet in the begin of data packet with short (int16) format
        List<byte> tmpdata = new List<byte>();
        tmpdata.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(buffer.Length + 2)));
        tmpdata.AddRange(buffer);
        buffer = tmpdata.ToArray();

        do
        {
            if (Environment.TickCount > startTickCount + timeout)
                throw new Exception("Sending packet was timeout.");
            try
            {
                sent += socket.Send(buffer, offset + sent, size - sent, SocketFlags.None);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                if (ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.WouldBlock ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.IOPending ||
                    ex.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.NoBufferSpaceAvailable)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(30);
                }
                else
                    throw ex;
            }
        } while (sent < size);
    }
```

Can someone help me?

---

Thanks Damien for the fix
And I was found the solution, but I am afraid this will consume memory usage since it looping each byte, here the code:

```
    public static byte[] Receive(Socket socket)
    {
        System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);
        int b = (byte)1;
        List<byte> databuf = new List<byte>();

        while ((b = ns.ReadByte()) != -1)
            databuf.Add((byte)b);

        return databuf.ToArray();
    }
```

There are any better solution without NetworkStream or maybe better performance?
Thanks

Comment: you should use `Bind()` and `Accept()` methods of server Socket it could be nice that you release your try to fix it.

Comment: Your read on the receiving end should only receive what you've sent to it.  Show your receiving code and explain the behavior you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are any better solution without NetworkStream or maybe better performance?

NetworkStream acts as a higher level wrapper for Socket, so you could do the same thing using it directly:

```
var targetStream = new MemoryStream();
var buffer = new byte[receiveBufferSize];
int bytesReceived = 0;

while ((bytesReceived = socket.Receive(buffer)) > 0)
{
    targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
}
```

Also there are `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync` methods in `Socket` that work well when you need to perform multiple concurrent operations. But they are more complicated:

```
var receive = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
var receiveBuffer = new byte[receiveBufferSize];
receive.SetBuffer(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length);
receive.Completed += HandleReceived;

if (!socket.ReceiveAsync(receive))
{
    HandleReceived(this, receive);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've not shown your receiving code, but one bug can be easily fixed:

```
    // Add size of packet in the begin of data packet with short (int16) format
    List<byte> tmpdata = new List<byte>();
    tmpdata.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((short)(buffer.Length + 2)));
    tmpdata.AddRange(buffer);
    buffer = tmpdata.ToArray();
    int size = buffer.Length; //Moved from higher up, now that buffer is a different size
```

At the receiving side, you should have similar code - loop until you've read 2 bytes, use that to create a `short` that is the total size to receive, subtract 2 (honestly, I'd just avoid adding 2 in the code above and have the size sent as the size *ignoring* the actual bytes used to encode the size), and then loop again until you've read the whole message.